# Pandas Time Series - Add difference from previous column to New Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, series

I have a DataFrame, DF:

```
    Ticker_x    Date    Close_x ES_difference
0   ES H7   10/18/2016 13:44    2128    
1   ES H7   10/18/2016 13:59    2128.75 0.75
2   ES H7   10/18/2016 14:14    2125.75 -3
3   ES H7   10/18/2016 14:29    2126.5  0.75
4   ES H7   10/18/2016 14:44    2126.5  0
5   ES H7   10/18/2016 16:14    2126    -0.5
6   ES H7   10/18/2016 16:44    2126.25 0.25
7   ES H7   10/18/2016 17:59    2126.5  0.25
8   ES H7   10/18/2016 18:14    2127    0.5
9   ES H7   10/18/2016 19:14    2127.75 0.75
10  ES H7   10/18/2016 19:44    2127.75 0
11  ES H7   10/18/2016 19:59    2127.75 0
12  ES H7   10/18/2016 20:44    2129    1.25
13  ES H7   10/18/2016 21:29    2128.75 -0.25
14  ES H7   10/18/2016 21:44    2129    0.25
15  ES H7   10/18/2016 22:14    2129.5  0.5
16  ES H7   10/18/2016 22:44    2129.5  0
```

I'm trying to make a new Column - `ES_Inverse_price` that takes the difference column and subtracts it from the `Close_x` column:

```
Df['ES_difference'] = Df['Close_x'].diff()
```

So that's how I made the `ES_difference` column. Now I want a new column `ES_Inverse_price` to take the previous value from `Close_x` and subtract the difference column value for the same row:

```
Df['ES_Inverse_price'] = ''
Df['ES_Inverse_price'][0] = Df['Close_x'][0]
Df['ES_Inverse_price'][1:] = Df['ES_Inverse_price'].shift(1)-Df['ES_difference']
```

...so the first row in `ES_Inverse_price` is going to equal the first row in `Close_x`. That's fine, but now I want to start subtracting that difference column to get a new value for the `ES_Inverse_price` column I'm trying to make.

Unfortunately, I get the following error referring to the code with the `shift(1)` in it:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')
```

edit: For example take row 1. Instead of being 2128.75, it'll be 2127.25. I'm subtracting the difference from 'Close_x' (already an established value) from the previous row's value, rather than adding it (which would give me 2128.75).

edit:

So in the example given by another poster below, here's what I'd be looking for:

```html
 close_p ticker difference ES_Inverse Price
0 100 aapl NaN NaN
1 102 aapl 2.0 98.0
2 103.4 aapl 1.4 96.6
3 101.2 aapl -2.2 98.8
4 106.2 aapl 5.0 93.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand unless you provide the values you are looking for but maybe this is it?

```
df['ES_Inverse_price'] = df['Close_x'].shift(1) - df['ES_difference']
```

Playing with some very rough data (I was having trouble copying yours):

```
df
   close_p ticker
0    100.0   aapl
1    102.0   aapl
2    103.4   aapl
3    101.2   aapl
4    106.2   apple

df['es_difference'] = df['close_p'].diff()
   close_p ticker  es_difference
0    100.0   aapl            NaN
1    102.0   aapl            2.0
2    103.4   aapl            1.4
3    101.2   aapl           -2.2
4    106.2   apple            5.0

df['es_inverse_price'] = df['close_p']-df['es_difference'].cumsum() - df['es_difference'].cumsum()
   close_p ticker  es_difference  es_inverse_price
0    100.0   aapl            NaN               NaN
1    102.0   aapl            2.0              98.0
2    103.4   aapl            1.4              96.6
3    101.2   aapl           -2.2              98.8
4    106.2   aapl            5.0              93.8
```

I wouldn't consider basing everything off `iloc[0,0]` to be "safe" but I'm not really sure how else to do it. Make sure you're sorting beforehand.

Comment: So I'm not trying to subtract the difference on 'Close_p' in your case. Rather, I'm trying to get the difference tacked onto the "ES_Inverse_price' column instead. Since the difference column is being subtracted the "ES_Inverse_price' column is going to steadily get more different from the "Close_p" (or "Close_x") column. So I think when you're taking "Close_p" there in the shift(1) code it's going to get a different result than I'm looking for. I  have the difference column there, I just want it subtracted from the new 'ES_Inverse_price' column previous value to arrive at the new row's value.

Comment: edit: Thanks for the comment, I added an example of what I'm looking for at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: Ok so you're subtracting es_difference (shifted down) from close_x? See edit

Comment: Not subtracting from close_x, but from the previous value of 'ES_Inverse_price'. So when close_x goes up, ES_Inverse_price will go down by the same amount

Comment: I would recommend using reproducible dummy data similar to what I've put together and manually create the column you're looking for. That way I can figure it out. In words I don't understand.

Comment: Ok will do I'll post it in the original

Comment: Just added updates. Not sure if this is really the best way to go but it'll get the job done. Removed `iloc` method.

Comment: @ColeStarbuck please also accept as answer if this solves it.